# Server-side sorting, asc/desc

Tags: spring-boot

I'm finishing up with my sorting stuff and I'm in front of a hurdle. I can sort by a specific field, but the direction is still hardcoded.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('service_manager')")
    @RequestMapping(path = "/clients", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<ClientResponse> getClients(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer size,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String companyName,
            @RequestParam(required = false) BigInteger firmRegNo,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String address,
            @RequestParam(required = false) BigInteger contractNo,
            @RequestParam(required = false) BigInteger monthlyPay,
            @RequestParam(required = false) User.UserStatus status,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "createTime") String sort,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "desc") String sortDir
            ) {

        ClientListRequest request = new ClientListRequest(companyName, firmRegNo, address, contractNo, monthlyPay, status);
        return clientService.getAllClients(request, of(page, size, Sort.Direction.DESC, sort))
                .map(ClientResponse::new);
    }
```

How can I alternate `Sort.Direction.DESC` and `Sort.Direction.ASC` depending on the parameter value of `sortDir`?

I tried this:

```
if (sortDir == "asc") {
            return clientService.getAllClients(request, of(page, size, Sort.Direction.ASC, sort))
                    .map(ClientResponse::new);
        } else {
            return clientService.getAllClients(request, of(page, size, Sort.Direction.DESC, sort))
                    .map(ClientResponse::new);
        }
```

Doesn't work and doesn't look right either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

```
Sort.Direction direction;

        if (sortDir.equals("asc")) {
            direction = Sort.Direction.ASC;
        } else {
            direction = Sort.Direction.DESC;
        }

        return clientService.getAllClients(request, of(page, size, direction, sort))
                    .map(ClientResponse::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, size, Sort.Direction.fromString(sortDir), sort);
    return repository.findAll(pageable);
```